# Scripted field in kibana for fields that are sometimes missing

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana-4

I have a scripted field "transferspeed" which is calculated as `"doc['bytes'].value / doc['duration'].value"`. The field is working but I get a Warning "Courier Fetch: 6 of 12 shards failed.".

I think this is because 'bytes' does not exist for all documents. How can i fix this, is it possible to adjust the script or do i have to add a 'bytes' field with 0 to the documents without bytes field?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you can live without documents that don't have either the `bytes` or
`duration` values (which might make sense, since you don't have a value without
them), you can use the
[exists](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-filter.html)
filter to limit your results to those documents with a `bytes` and `duration`
field.

Answer (score 0):

Well , you will need to check if these fields are present before taking its value.
Something like -

```
If(doc.contains('bytes') && doc.contains('duration')){
       // Do computation
}
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: That doesn't work, I tried already to check if the fields are present but always got a compile error and here I also get a compile error. ParseException:  unexpected character ''' at position (16). I think there is no if allowed in scripted fields ... [link](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting.html#_lucene_expressions_scripts)

Comment: Can you past the entire command you are using. I am guessing you are doing from commandline

Comment: I'm doing it in Kibana Indices -> Scripted Fields -> Add Scripted Field and there are two fields, Name and Script. Name is "transferspeed" and Script is "doc['bytes'].value / doc['duration'].value". The calculation is working for documents that have both fields but the elasticserch server throws exceptions for the other documents without

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
if(doc['bytes'].value!=null && doc['duration'].value!=null) {
   return doc['bytes'].value / doc['duration'].value
}
```